# Why window size, TCP segment is increasing in wireShark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I submit text file to server capturing by wireShark. my computer's window size is steady to 17408. but server's window size is increasing 6912, 9856, 12800 ...

I want to know why server's window size is increasing. and first TCP segment data is 502 bytes. and the other TCP segment is 1460 bytes.

why window size is increasing? why first TCP segment data is different the other?

Comment: Off topic, but it all sounds like normal TCP slow starting to me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the growth of TCP window size is related to the so-called slow start algorithm, which is described in detail here [TCP Slow start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start)

Also in the program Wireshark is a definite option to recompile the TCP-packets in accordance with the useful content L7, so that the size of the package there may be, in principle, any 
For example, if a set of TCP-packets, which are encapsulated huge HTTP-request, instead of breaking in fragments, it can be shown in one huge fake TCP-packet
This option is called TCP reassemble